# Strange behviour of state in slice redux-toolkit (revoked proxy)

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, immer.js

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ucjrx?file=/src/features/todos/todosSlice.js

In todoSlice.js, at line 14, when I try to do console.log, it is printed as a revoked proxy (browser console). But when I put a breakpoint in chrome dev tools and go through that line step by step, it is not a revoked proxy.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a RTK reducer, your state is wrapped in a Proxy object by the immer library to detect modifications. After the reducer is finished, that proxy object is revoked to prevent memory leaks.

Unfortunately, `console.log` does not log a in-time snapshot of an object, but a reference - and the time you try to actually explore these contents, it's already revoked.

[As the documentation explains](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#logging-draft-state-values), you should log draft state values using the `current` export from immer that is re-exported from RTK:

```js
import { createSlice, current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState: [{ id: 1, title: 'Example todo' }],
  reducers: {
    addTodo: (state, action) => {
      console.log('before', current(state))
      state.push(action.payload)
      console.log('after', current(state))
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Just when I thought redux could not get more abstract and over-engineered. Front-end dev has become a nightmare with all of these tools that solve 1 problem and create dozens new ones.

Comment: @Organic That has nothing to do with Redux, but with how browsers are logging things. Benefit of the thing: you just write 1/4 of the code compared to legacy Redux. Also, this "problem" is shared by lots of state management libraries that use abstractions like this.

Comment: @Organic Couldn't agree more.